# Remove Document variables for OpenXML DOCX?

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to remove the `doc` variables from a DOCX file. Here is the code I'm using, but it doesn't remove any...

This is the complete code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filePath = "C:\\..\\..sample.docx";
            Remove removedocvars = new Remove();
            removedocvars.RemoveDocVariables(filePath);

        }
    }

//method to remove doc vars
  public void RemoveDocVariables(string fileName)
        {
            using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, true))
            {

                List<DocumentVariables> DocVarsToDelete = doc.MainDocumentPart.RootElement.Descendants<DocumentVariables>().ToList();
                foreach (DocumentVariables dc in DocVarsToDelete)
                {
                    dc.Remove();
                }
                doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

the variables are in the settings.xml file, so you have to use MainDocumentPart.DocumentSettingsPart.Settings.Descendants<>().

```
public void RemoveDocVariables(string fileName)
{
    using (var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, true))
    {
        doc.MainDocumentPart.DocumentSettingsPart.Settings.RemoveAllChildren<DocumentVariables>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is the extent of your code, then aren't you missing a call to the save method?

Something like:

```
    foreach (DocumentVariable dc in DocVarsToDelete)
    {
        dc.Remove();
    } 
    document.Save();
```

Comment: AFAIK `Save` is called automatically when disposing the document in later versions of the SDK.

Comment: Good to know. I looked at some other sample code (that didn't use a Using block) and noticed the method was missing.

Comment: well. my complete code includes the document.Save(), and still and it never worked. so I was wondering if there is any other way to remove the document variables

Comment: Perhaps you should show your complete code then. There might be a simple problem that another set of eyes can catch.

Answer (score 0):

This is a 6 years old question, but I think it still would be valuable to add the answer. Your issue likely is related to this:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/issues/198

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/issues/222

OpenXML used to be not like mixing of accessing mechanism until the patch mentioned in one of the link above was applied.

Comment: Even though Github links will probably last for a bit, it would be beneficial to add some context from either link to your answer in the event those links do disappear.